# Finder and Devices section

Tags: finder

Till some days ago, the external USB drive `FA_SAMSUNG` used to appear in the `Devices`section of a Finder window. See attached screenshot.

[image]

All of a sudden, both drives disappeared from that section: the internal SSD and the USB external. I was able to add the SSD back to that section by dragging its icon. But I find no way to have the external USB drive back in the `Devices` section: if I drag its icon into that list, the icon goes back where it was.

I am using OS X 10.11.6.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to check is your Finder preferences.

1. In the Finder, go to Finder > Preferences
2. Select the Sidebar tab
3. Now check to make sure that both the Hard Disks and External Disks option are selected
4. Close the Finder Preferences window

Comment: Thanks!!! I had a quick look at the preferences and saw everything checked, but after your reply I noticed that the blue check was different!